# ${aspnet-request-method} Layout Renderer Not Working

Tags: .net, nlog

So I have a .Net Framework 4.7.2 Web API server and I want to log certain stuff like the request method, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my **NLog.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
    >
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:/ProgramData/ISEM10/Logs/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-OnboardMonitoring.json" >
            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeEventProperties="true" excludeProperties="Comma-separated list (string)">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
                <attribute name="Location" layout="${callsite:className=False:fileName=True:includeSourcePath=True:methodName=True}" />
                <attribute name="RequestMethod" layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="OnboardMonitoring" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="jsonFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

However the logging generated looks like this:

```
{ "time": "2022-10-05 17:04:44.4082", "level": "INFO", "message": "Finished fetching data", "Location": "GetOnboardCaseDetail(D:\\ISEM10\\CORAL-ISEM-BE\\AMLP\\Areas\\OnboardMonitoring\\Controllers\\OnboardCaseWorkflowController.cs:74)" }
```

As you can see, it deosn't include the `RequestMethod` key and value. I have already tried with both **Nlog.Web.Core** and **NLog.Web**, neither seems to be working. Not sure if there's anything else I am supposed to do to make it work. The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything either.

Would appreciate any help you guys can throw my way.

EDIT: Turning on internal logging yields the following error:

```
2022-10-06 10:20:50.4113 Debug No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context. Logger: OnboardMonitoring
```

Comment: Have you checked the output NLog InternalLogger at Debug-Level ? See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: @RolfKristensen It gives the following error:
**2022-10-06 10:20:50.4113 Debug No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context.** . How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked that a valid HttpContext is available when logging `"Finished fetching data"` ? Notice that if the HttpRequest triggers an async-task or background-thread, then any logging performed by the async-task or background-thread will not have access to the original HttpContext. Consider using [NLog ScopeContext](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks alot for the help. I just couldn't figure out why my httpcontext was being empty. It was caused exactly because I was testing it inside a async-task. I used the ScopeContext and everything is working fine now. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that a valid HttpContext is available when logging `"Finished fetching data"` ?

Notice that if the HttpRequest triggers an async-task or background-thread, then any logging performed by the async-task or background-thread will not have access to the original HttpContext.

Consider using [NLog ScopeContext](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context):

```
using (NLog.ScopeContext.PushProperty("RequestMethod", "Hello_Method"))
{
    // Start async-task
}
```

```xml
<attribute name="RequestMethod" layout="${aspnet-request-method:whenEmpty=${scopeproperty=RequestMethod}}" />
```